# Magento2: Order updated_at stored in DB in timezone CEST but delivered/transformed to UTC by $order->getUpdatedAt in Environment "crontab"

Tags: magento2, sales-order, crontab, timezone

we are facing a strange behavior for value of updated_at saved in db table sales_order. Server timezone is CEST, updated_at date therefor is saved in CEST to database. This is validated. Default config timezone is "Europe/Berlin".

Cron job collects orders with specific state via resource collection to manipulate them. Debugging updated_at value by looping result set prints value/date in UTC, its -2h. This runs in "crontab" environment/area. This happens (in loop) for all those calls:

```
echo $order->getUpdatedAt();
echo $order->getData('updated_at');
echo $order->getOrigData('updated_at'); 

//Collection load
$criteria = $this->criteriaBuilder->addFilter('state', Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW)->create();
$items = $this->orderRepository->getList($criteria)->getItems();
```

We checked mostly every possibility why and how this transformation happens but we didn't find any hint in code. We found no after collection load observer or any other forced transformation. Magento folks, what could cause this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have u build custom collection for  your cronjob?

Comment: Added collection load to my question.

Comment: I guess that You have to changes time `criteriaBuilder` section.

Comment: You think searchCriteriaBuilder modifies date format / timezones dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

after hours of debugging we found the issue. MySQL and server configured timezone is CEST. So all native queries done by PHP or direct mysql shows date in configured timezone CEST. All application based result sets doesn't because of following query fired in \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::_connect.

```
$this->_connection->query("SET time_zone = '+00:00'");
```

So internally Magento2 sets time_zone to UTC, what is fine but not known ;).

Cheers